# Two mqtt connections same device

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I'm developing software for Android which communicates with external tools using a JMS through MQTT protocol. I've seen that they start working wrongly when two of them are running at the same time keeping the MQTT connection alive. I'm using this [library](https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client).

I'm having several issues, especially "pair disconnected".I know this happen when another mqtt connection is created. However, I don't know if there is any way to deal with it so that I can have two connections opened at the same time in the same device.

Curiously, I'm not having the same experience when executing the same code in a computer as a java application. I can run as many java apps as I want that creates a connection if it's executed on a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have set the same client id in both clients. The client id must be unique on the broker.